# SurfaceView transparency problem

Tags: android, transparency, surfaceview

I have this problem: i added two view instances in a framelayout. First view is a VideoView which plays in loop a video. Second view is placed above the videoview and is a surfaceview. The surfaceview draws some .png's an a white rectangle which needs a small part of the screen. The part that is not needed must be transparent. in order to do that i used the next code lines (surfaceview implemnts SurfaceHolder.Callback):

```
setZOrderOnTop(true);
getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.Transparent);
```

The problem is that i want to make the white rectangle semitransparent in order to see the movie played by the videoview. The transparency effect works fine on the non used part of the surfaceview but the rectangle does not became semitransparent(if a i draw a background to surfaceview the effect becomes visible.) I wait a solution from u guys.Thx

Comment: Have you set paint.setAlpha(0.5f) for your white rectangle paint?

Comment: sorry it worked you are a genius...:P

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the SurfaceHolder doesn't allow alpha. Have you checked the result of PixelFormat.formatHasAlpha()? Or have you tried explicitly setting PixelFormat.RGBA_4444, RGBA_5551 or RGBA_8888 to see what happens?

Comment: yes, the return is true. also i used the pixelformat u suggested and does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
mVideoView.setZOrderOnTop( true );
getHolder().setFormat( PixelFormat.RGBA_8888 );
```

Worked for me.